# Ubuntu Netbeans 6.9 is ugly

Tags: php, netbeans, ubuntu, netbeans-6.9

The fonts and everything is just ugly in Ubuntu 11.04. Do you know how to change it, to make it look like in Windows? Or maybe you know other good PHP editor?

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. To me Netbeans sends me into a mild Euphoria that renders me unable to operate a vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maby you could try Aptana as an editor: http://aptana.com/products/studio3/download

Answer (score 1):

Manually edit the `netbeans.conf` file, located in the `/etc` folder. Add the switchs: `-J-Dswing.aatext=true` and `-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on` to the section `netbeans_default_options`

Comment: Can you post your netbeans.conf file?

Comment: Maybe you can post yours and I will just paste?

Comment: The relevant line, for me, looks like this: `netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xverify:none -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on"`

Answer (score 0):

try to install sun java or switch to it 
other good php editor - phpStorm ( not free )

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't a huge fan of the way the netbeans editor part looked, and I had trouble with the fonts as well.  I switched to DejaVu LGC Sans mono, and it looks better.  I also started using the 'twilight' theme that someone made (http://taylorpennock.com/netbeans-check-a-great-twilight-theme-for-net)

You may also want to update to 7 or whatever the current version is.  I have some issues with 6.9.1 that I've found are fixed in 7.